# Color Ramp not recognizing textures

Tags: texturing

Basically I am following a [Ducky tutorial](https://youtu.be/icMn25j2yy0?t=748) and for some reason when I try to use a *Color Ramp* with any texture connected to it, it doesn't recognize it and just acts as if there is no texture connected at all.

[image: Color Ramp white]
[image: Color ramp black]

Answer (score 1):

Ok false alarm, the fix was just adding a mapping and texture coordinate AND using the object option on the color coordinate